# How can I copy data from textboxes to a row determined by the value of a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I now have code that uses Loop to copy sets of data in a worksheet to and from TextBoxes using Arrays where the data is either stored across a row or down a column. In all instances the Dictionary "Key" uses a different array of columns.

I am now looking to move data from sequential TextBoxes to the same array of columns but where each Key relates to a different Row

Dictionary Array  (Columns "C", "D", "E", "D")

Dictionary Key Values are Data1, Data2, Data2

- So if Key = Data1 Then copy to Array Columns in Row 2
- So if Key = Data2 Then copy to Array Columns in Row 3  etc

This sample code excludes the Variable details - I am more interested in how I can achieve the desired results in the "active" code

```
Private Sub cmdCallDcata_Click()
    Set DataToColsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
        With DataToColsDict
            .Add "Data1", Array("C", "D", "E", "F")
            .Add "Data2", Array("C", "D", "E", "F")
        End With
        With Me
                vCols = DataToColsDict(.cboDataNumber.Value)
            tbCounter = 1
                For lngRowLoop = 2 To 3
                    For Each vCol In vCols
                        .Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = ws.Cells(lngRowLoop, vCol).Text
                    tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
                    Next
                Next
        End With
End Sub
```

This code will populate both rows.

I have tried by having only 1 line ("Data1") in the Dictionary and a single row in the loop, but the code fails when the value of cboDataNumber is not "Data1"

Comment: How many text boxes on the form ? "This code will populate both rows." ? The code shown populates text boxes from a sheet

Comment: In one instance II have 2 similar groups one with 6 Text Boxes and one with 13, however thay have separate comand buttons. Regardless, I wish to use the code on a number of userforms, hence why I provided sample code. Apologies, for the error in the directron of the information, but I use the code to move information in both directions.  I receive a variety of error messages depending on the different changes I make to try to get the code to work.

Comment: I believe that perhaps this syntax is unsuitable for what I am trying to achieve, 
Move details from a series of textboxes into different rows depending on the value of a ComboBox, In all cases the same range of columns will be used

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set DataToColsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set DataToRowsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With DataToColsDict
        .Add "Data1", Array("C", "D", "E", "F")
        .Add "Data2", Array("C", "D", "E", "F")
    End With
    With DataToRowsDict
        .Add "Data1", Array(2, 3)
        .Add "Data2", Array(5, 6)
    End With
    
    With Me
        s = "Data1" '.cboDataNumber.Value
        vCols = DataToColsDict(s)
        vRows = DataToRowsDict(s)
        
        tbCounter = 1
        For Each vRow In vRows
            For Each vCol In vCols
                ws.Cells(vRow, vCol).Value = .Controls("textBox" & tbCounter).Text
                tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this code. I am experiencing problems understanding how to populate the first line of With Me as I have 2 possible Dictionaries with "Data1" and I get the error that variable  S has not been defined.

Comment: @Denny change that line to `s = Me.cboDataNumber.Value`

Comment: Same Error  "Variable Not Defined".  I have checked for typos but found none

Comment: @denny Which line is error on ? variable is `s` not `5`. Add Dim s

Comment: s = "Data1" '.cboDataNumber.Value   "S =" is being highlighted. as the error

Comment: Excellent..Thank you.  Big learning curve for me but this has saved many individual lines of code